# ls or find option to exclude binary files

Tags: find, ls, binary

How can I list only files that aren't compiled code in the current directory?

I'm reviewing the custom scripts and code on several HPUX and Linux servers before transferring them to a newer system. I get tired of seeing `PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY` when I encounter a file that is compiled.

I would like to sort them so that I can skip over the compiled software and come back to them at a later time.

Comment: maybe `file * | grep -v ELF` (not tested)

Comment: Your listing has to include file size and rights? Having just the file path is enough?

Comment: `file * | grep -v ELF` will work if there are no other options, but I'd prefer to list them with file size and rights but exclude the executables.

Comment: If you use `less` or `view` or several other programs, they'll avoid spewing control sequences to your terminal when you open binary files.

Comment: So I guess I can use the following line and create an alias for it `file * | grep -v ELF | grep -v executable | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/://g' | xargs ls -l`. @pmg you helped me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8):

It bends the use of grep a bit

```
grep -r -I -l .
```

But it will list all non binary file in current directory. Using mostly  the `-I` switch to exclude binary

Comment: It will recursively list files under that directory also. OP asked for current directory only.

Comment: @DrBeco just drop the -r option

Answer (score 2):

When ignoring files **with the executable bit** set, I just use this command:

```
find . ! -perm -111
```

To keep it from recursively enter into other directories:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -perm -111
```

No need for *pipes* to mix lots of commands, just the powerful plain *find* command.

PS. Reference also [link to my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767396/linux-command-how-to-find-only-text-files/43421299#43421299)

Answer (score 0):

It should work,

```
file * | egrep -v 'ELF|executable' | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/://g' | xargs ls -l
```